# Setting vectors in shaders, How does it work? OpenGL GLSL

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, glsles

I am trying to understand how vertex and fragment shaders work in OpenGL ES 2.0.

My shaders look like this:

*vertex shader:*

```
// source code for the vertex shader
attribute vec4 vPosition
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vPosition;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

*fragment shader:*

```
// source code for the fragment shader
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord);
}
```

The program that uses those shaders draws a simple 2D rectangle with a texture (an image). First it passes the vertices of the rectangle and the texture coords to the vertex shader with attributes. Then the vertex shader passes the texture coords with a varying to the fragment shader.

What confuses me is that the vectors vPosition, a_texCoord and v_texCoord can only save 1 Point, but need to save 4 diffrent Points. I read somewhere that the vertex shader will be called for each vertex. Does that mean the vertex and fragment shader will be processed 4 times for each image i want to draw? When I define the attributes (glVertexAttribPointer) I am using an array with 4 points, how can the shaders save 4 points in a variable that can only store 1 point?

I want to use uniforms instead of attributes, i read its better. Also i wouldnt need the varying variable. I would like to have it like this:

*vertex shader:*

```
// source code for the vertex shader
uniform vec4 vPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vPosition;
}
```

*fragment shader:*

```
// source code for the fragment shader
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
uniform vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord);
}
```

Is this possible? Can I still pass all the points that i need to the shaders? Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not store the per vertex data into the uniform. A uniform is designed to be per draw call and a vertex attribute is designed to be per vertex. The only way you could use your vertex position with a uniform would be for drawing a point since it uses only 1 coordinate.

So about the vertices and the processing: Yes, if you draw with 4 vertices there will be at least 4 calls to your vertex shader for those vertices to be processed. You have nothing to worry about this, imagine that drawing a 100x100 image using 4 vertices there will be 4 calls to the vertex shader and 10000(100x100) calls to the fragment shader. This is what the GPU is designed for, it does it extremely efficiently.

You may look at some full charts of the openGL pipelines to understand everything better but just to give you a clue on what is going on when you call the openGL to draw:

- Depending on the shape you are drawing (e.g. triangles) a number of points will be taken and processed in the vertex shader, this includes all attributes such as position, texture coordinates, normals...
- Next a rasterization will happen at which point all the pixels on the buffer will be determined to be drawn to and for each of those a fragment shader will be assigned.
- Then the fragment shader takes place which will receive all interpolated values and fixed uniforms it needs and refresh a single specific pixel in every attached buffer you are currently using (color, depth...).

Now again there is quite a lot more to this pipeline then I described but these are most interesting for the questions you are asking.

Try to understand that shaders are just a part of a long fixed pipeline which can now be overridden, you should not be asking yourself how many times they are called at least not for the simple operation as the one you are doing. If you need to optimize the number of these calls you will most likely need to optimize on the CPU. For instance if you are drawing a few thousands of large rectangles overlapping each other you could think of the algorithm to reduce the size needed to draw a rectangle which is mostly overlapped by others or even not draw it at all if it is fully overlapped.

So to understand what goes on from the shaders you posted: If you are drawing a textured rectangle you will have 4 or 6 calls to the vertex shader (6 using two triangles). The vertex shader will receive all enabled attributes which in your case are position and texture coordinate. Nothing is done with this two values but passed forward at this point. Then the position is automated (you do not need another varying parameter to pass it on) but the texture coordinate is assigned to a varying property you called `v_texCoord`. This means that the texture coordinate will be interpolated for each of the pixels that are going to be drawn and those values are then received in the fragment shader. That is the reason why you can actually see the drawn texture as each of the pixel has a different color taken from the texture with a different interpolated coordinate received by the fragment shader. So replacing the attribute with an uniform will break all this, no interpolations will happen and all your pixels will look exactly the same.